# AltBeacon: didExitRegion and didEnterRegion alternation

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I've been working with the android beacon library (AltBeacon) and I'm having the following problems:

- When a didEnterRegion event is detected is always followed by a
  didExitRegion for the same region. Then, 20 - 30 seconds later (is
  not immediately), a didEnterRegion event is fired again and the
  process repeats.
- Right now I'm working with 3 beacons representing 3 different regions
  and sometimes, when I turn them on gradually, every didEnterRegion of
  a single region triggers a didExitRegion event for the other active
  regions.

I'm using a Moto G (4.4.4) with the WiFi turned off (I also tested on a BQ Aquarius 5 and the error persists).
The beacons I'm using are April Beacon from April Brother and their configuration is:
TxPower: 0bdm
Adv(ms): 9

I've tried with different advertisement values and with different scanning period times but the problem persists.

Here's the log I took today:

http://pastebin.com/wxVdsfGz

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the log, it appears the beacons are transmitting infrequently.  Beacons should transmit every second or more for proper results.

Comment: And do you know how can I fix this problem? We used an iPhone transmiting as an iBeacon and it happened exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the library's reference application to see if you can reproduce the problem there.

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Note you will have to supply a custom BeaconParser so it will detect your proprietary beacons.

Because you have tried with two different beacon transmitters and two different phones, I doubt the problem is with either the phones or the transmitters.

The most likely remaining source of the issue is the code in your app.  To confirm this please try the reference app and see if that works properly.  If it does, you will need to post your code so we can help figure out the issue.

Comment: It happens exactly the same. I receive enter / exit messages with a certain periodicity

Comment: This is not my experience with the reference app at all.  I have tested it with several types of beacon transmitters, and as long as they are transmitting often enough (once a second is fine), I get an entry notification and no exit notification until the beacon is no longer in the vicinity.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else to suggest since I cannot reproduce your findings.